# missing data in req.body due to 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked' instead of content length

Tags: node.js, http

We have `put` some data to node server but some time data(req.body) is missing. When I checked request-header then I get `'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'`

It seems no content-length (means no request body). Issue is always coming from nexus phone with arbitrary manner. (It's a strange thing)

one more thing header also have `'x-forwarded-for': 'XX.XXX.XXX.XXX, X.XX.X.XX'` , when content length missing.

I hope you get my points. 
Can anybody explain me reason of this issue and How can we resolve this kind of issue ???

Is coming due to any RFC standard breaking OR anything else???

**EDIT :: Issue is coming due to Volley library of android.**

Answer (score -1):

Issue is coming due to Volley library of android.

Comment: That's an addition to your question, not an answer.